# Generating S5 presentations using Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, s5

Is there some way to generate [S5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S5_%28file_format%29) presentations directly out of Sphinx projects using Sphinx 1.0.7?

I found multiple reference to a built-in S5 builder in Sphinx but did not find anything useful except related code in docutils.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

While not S5, there is the following [theme](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxjp.themes.htmlslide) for Sphinx slides.

And the [code](https://bitbucket.org/shimizukawa/sphinxjp.themes.htmlslide) is available, so you can tweak it to be more S5 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

So Sphinx has a docutils backend. My guess is that you read about the docutils S5 backend.
http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/slide-shows.html#s5-theme-files

From looking at the documentation for the current stable and development releases, Sphinx does not appear to have a direct S5 backend.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [Hieroglyph](https://hieroglyph.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) project: it produces HTML5 slides using the Sphinx processing system, apparently. I have not used it, nor do I know how S5-compliant it is.